# jQuery element creation, value passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('#stuff_btn').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

$(this).remove();
$('#stuff').prepend('<div id="current_lvl">Level: 1</div>');

var words = ["arvuti","pudel","ekraan"];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
var word = words[random];   
var chars = word.split('');
chars = _.shuffle(chars);

for(var i in chars)
{
    $('#word_place_grid ul').append('<li id="letter' + i + '">' +  chars[i] +  '</li>');

    $('#letter'+i).bind('click',function(){
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.30,
            top: -55,
        },750,function(){    //Animation complete
            $('#game_window_grid ul').append('<li>' + chars[i] + '</li>');
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
}
```

})

HTML:

```
    <div class="word_grid" id="game_window_grid">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="word_grid" id="word_place_grid">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I am trying to take a word randomly from the list. Shuffle the letters. Put each letter to a separate li in the dic #word_place_grid. Then I wan to add the click handler to each div that would animate that li and in the end of the animation I would like to add the value of the animated li to a new li element that I append to the div #game_window_grid.
The problem is that with the jQuery code I have right now, it will add the last random character from the list: chars to all of the li elements that I add to the div #game_window_grid. No matter which way I try to rewrite the code, I still cant get the right value for li.

Any idea what I should change or what should I do to get the correct value for the div #game_window_grid li ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you jsfiddle.net this please?

Comment: Classic for loop issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull this out...

```
$('#letter'+i).bind('click',function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.30,
        top: -55,
    },750,function(){    //Animation complete
        $('#game_window_grid ul').append('<li>' + chars[i] + '</li>');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Put this somewhere else...

```
$('#word_place_grid').on('click', '[id^=letter]', function(){
  var character = $(this).text();
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.30,
        top: -55,
    },750,function(){    //Animation complete
        $('#game_window_grid ul').append('<li>' + character + '</li>');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Edit: Alternatively you can get rid of the for...in loop and replace with `$.each()` as your iterator

```
$.each(chars, function(i, character) {
  $('#word_place_grid ul').append('<li id="letter' + i + '">' +  character +  '</li>');
  $('#letter'+i).on('click',function(){
      $(this).animate({
          opacity: 0.30,
          top: -55,
      },750,function(){    //Animation complete
          $('#game_window_grid ul').append('<li>' + character + '</li>');
          $(this).remove();
      });
  });
});
```

P.S. `.bind()` is not as widely used as of jQuery 1.7 `.on()` contains the same functionality with the added benefit of delegated events that can occur after the page is loaded (this is how my original answer works to find the dynamically added elements `[id^=letter]`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain in a few words why this works? I would appreciate it :)

Comment: I think the issue is the for...in loop as mentioned. For whatever reason inside your `.bind()` callback the value of `i` is always the last index of your `chars` array. [Some say you shouldn't use for...in for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea), I would suggest using `$.each()` to replace this (See my edit above). The first solution I provided doesn't use `i`, it reads the `.text()`, to find the value of the character (which isn't contained within the for...in loop) so it's not a problem in that case.